# python lxml write to file in predefined order

Tags: python, sorting, lxml, elementtree

I want to write following **lxml etree subelements**:

```
<ElementProtocolat0x3803048>,
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108>,
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248>,
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>,
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408>,
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>,
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8>,
```

to my odm xml file in a **predefined order**. i.e.

```
<ElementProtocolat0x3803048>,
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108>,
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248>,
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8>,
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>,
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>,
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408>,
....
```

is there any way to sort the elements i.e. with a predefined list?

```
predefined_order = ['Protocol', 'StudyEventDef','FormDef','ItemGroupDef','ItemDef','CodeList']
```

Comment: where is `ClinicalData`?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I forgot it it's at the last position..
predefined_order = ['Protocol', 'StudyEventDef','FormDef','ItemGroupDef','ItemDef','CodeList', 'ClinicalData']

Comment: are the subelements strings in a list?

Comment: no they are in an ElementTree object: 
etree.SubElement(root, 'FormDef')

Comment: Are you asking how to reorder an lxml tree, or are you asking how to sort based on a predefined list? If it is the former, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385358/lxml-sorting-tag-order

Comment: I already saw this post thanks. I don't want to order the tags alphabetic, but I want to order them with a predefined list, so it's actually a combination of both :)

Comment: what if predefined list does not contain an element of the data (lxml etree subelements) ?!

Comment: This is impossible because odm is a data standard andtherefore i know what subelements are required...

Comment: This is required for me to ask as I have no knowledge on xml. But I have a quite good solution in basic python. Posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample demonstrates:

- How to read in an XMl file,
- That an Element is a list, and can be manipulated as such
- How to sort a list based on the predefined order of a matchable substring
- How to write out an XML file

```python
from lxml import etree
import re

# Parse the XML and find the root
with open('input.xml') as input_file:
    tree = etree.parse(input_file)
root = tree.getroot()

# Find the list to sort and sort it
some_arbitrary_expression_to_find_the_list = '.'
element_list = tree.xpath(some_arbitrary_expression_to_find_the_list)[0]

predefined_order = [
    'Protocol',
    'StudyEventDef',
    'FormDef',
    'ItemGroupDef',
    'ItemGroupData',
    'ItemDef',
    'CodeList',
    'ClinicalData']
filter = re.compile(r'Element(.*)at0x.*')

element_list[:] = sorted(
    element_list[:],
    key = lambda x: predefined_order.index(filter.match(x.tag).group(1)))

# Write the XML to the output file
with open('output.xml', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True))
```

Sample input:

```
<stuff>
<ElementProtocolat0x3803048 />
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108 />
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248 />
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>Random Text</ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408 />
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8><tag1><tag2 attr="random tags"/></tag1></ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8 />
</stuff>
```

OUtput:

```
<stuff>
<ElementProtocolat0x3803048/>
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108/>
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248/>
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8/>
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>Random Text</ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8><tag1><tag2 attr="random tags"/></tag1></ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408/>
</stuff>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! in the end I solved the problem with a for loop but that is much nicer solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my lack of knowledge on xml but I tried to format your data in sorted order using my basic knowledge of Python only.

```
import re
data = """<ElementProtocolat0x3803048>,
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108>,
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248>,
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>,
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408>,
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>,
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8>,"""

predefined_order = ['Protocol','StudyEventDef','FormDef','ItemGroupDef','ItemGroupData','CodeList', 'ClinicalData']

fh1 = open("something.xml","w")
for i in predefined_order:
    for j in data.split(','):
        if re.search(i,j):
            fh1.write(j + ',')
```

Output:

```
<ElementProtocolat0x3803048>,
<ElementStudyEventDefat0x3803108>,
<ElementFormDefat0x3803248>,
<ElementFormDefat0x38036c8>,
<ElementItemGroupDefat0x38032c8>,
<ElementItemGroupDataat0x38035c8>,
<ElementClinicalDataat0x3803408>,
```